# Run a Django app on PyPy on Amazon AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, pypy, aws-cli

I have a Django application, that does some intensive computational tasks. To make its execution faster I run it with PyPy (the Python alternative extension to run scripts faster).

I have to deploy it on amazon-aws (Elastic Beanstalk). I want to deploy it, such that it runs on PyPy on aws, (and not on conventional/default Python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to run PyPy (also on AWS) is to install it (pypy is bundled these days with the default AWS distribution) and use virtualenv to manage python dependencies.

Comment: So if its bundled with aws, this means i donot need to install it, and yeah dependencies are managed using virtualenv, so this means if i simply deploy on aws, it will run using pypy ?, or how there is a way to explicitly make sure that app is run using pypy ?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-available-amazon-linux-ami-2015-09/ here are the instructions how to install pypy on amazon ami